# C/C++ XMPP library which works on both Android (NDK) and iOS

Tags: c++, c, xmpp, poco-libraries, swiften

I am looking for a C/C++ library which will run on both Android and iOS without much dependency/compilation issues. Any suggestions and recoomendations?

So far I've seen POCO and Switen. Any recommendation on either of them or an alternative?

(using Android NDK is ok for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used POCO on iOS/Android and it was very straightforward, dynamic pointers. There was some threshold on getting it running at first, but once first sample was running: no problems... You may want to check out our entire project [here](https://github.com/devdavidkarlsson/Sogeti-MasterThesis-CrossPlatformMobileDevelopment)